# Difficulty in understanding Manager's accent(language and communication)

Tags: communication, work-environment, team, manager

I am working for an IT company and recently got moved to a different team. Obviously, under a different Manager. My Manager is so compatible in all terms. However,I have a problem. I am not able to understand his way of talking. In other words, I don't understand his accent. Is there any way I can overcome this? Because of this, I blink in meetings and unable to respond promptly. Can I confess about this to my Manager or Is there any other way to Manage such situations?

Thanks! If this question is a repetition, Let me know the original link as I am not able to spot that one.

Comment: Are you both native speakers?

Comment: Just speak to them about it. Over time you will start to understand him.